HtmlBundlerPlugin error, import at-rules in CSS is not bug?
src/index.html
src/layout/header.html
src/css/common/iconfont.css

head.html:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@styles/common/iconfont.css">
index.html:
<%~ include('layout/header.html',{title:title}) %>
webpack config:
module.exports = (env, argv) =>{
  const isProd = argv.mode === 'production';

  return {
    mode: argv.mode,
    devtool: isProd?'hidden-source-map':'eval-cheap-module-source-map',   
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@scripts': path.join(__dirname, 'src/js/'),
        '@styles': path.join(__dirname, 'src/css/'),,
        '@fonts': path.join(__dirname, 'src/fonts/'),
      },
    },
    plugins:[
      new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
        entry: {
          index: {
            import: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
            data: { title: 'index' },
          },
          contact:{
            import: path.join(__dirname, 'src/page-contact.html'),
            data: { title: 'contact' },
          }
        },
        preprocessor: 'eta',
        preprocessorOptions: {
          views: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
            js: {
              filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
              inline: {
                chunk: [/runtime.+[.]js/],
              },
            },
            css: {
              filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
            },
            minify: {
              removeComments: true,
              collapseWhitespace: false, 
              minifyJS: true, 
              minifyCSS: true,
            },
          }),
    ],
    module:{
      rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|svg)$/,
            type: 'asset',
            parser:{
              dataUrlCondition:{ maxSize: 10*1024 }
            },
            generator:{
                filename: 'images/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
            },
          },
          { 
            test: /\.css$/i, 
            use: [
              'css-loader',
              {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                  postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [['postcss-preset-env']],
                  },
                },
              }
            ],
          }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), 
      watchFiles: {
        paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src/**/*.*') ],
        options: {
          usePolling: false,
        },
      },
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        minSize: 30,              
        cacheGroups: {           
            default: {  
                name: 'commons',  
                chunks: 'all',  
                minChunks: 2,   
                priority: -20, 
            },
            vendors: {                            
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,   
              name: 'vendor',                   
              chunks: 'all',
              priority: -10                    
            }
        },
      },
    },
  };
}

error:
PluginException:
HTML Bundler Plugin Can't resolve D:\webpack\src\css\common\iconfont.css in the file src\page-contact.html
The handling of @import at-rules in CSS is not supported. Disable the 'import' option in 'css-loader':
{
  test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
        import: false, // disable @import at-rules handling
      },
    },
  ],
},

When I run dev, an error occurs. How can I modify and solve it? It seems that there is an error in the alias reference to the css when packaging.
Only index.html runs normally, but when page-contact.html (including header.html and footer.html) is added and run, an error is reported.

Can you please create a small repo with reproducible issue, then I can help you to configure your project.
You can create the issue directly here: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/issues

does the config contain the CSS rule?
module: { rules: [{ test: /\.css$/, use: ['css-loader'] }] }

please provide full webpack configuration

The problem is in the splitChunks configuration.
Webpack compile all assets in JavaScript modules and split it, including CSS modules defined in HTML. Therefore CSS files are lost.
Solution
Add the test option to every splitChunks.cacheGroups to avoid splitting of CSS files:
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      minSize: 100,
      cacheGroups: {
        default: {
          test: /.+\.(js|ts)$/, // <= split only scripts, excluding style files
          name: 'commons',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
        },
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].+\.(js|ts)$/, // <= split only scripts, excluding style files
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          priority: -10,
        },
      },
    },
  },


Thanks for answering!
There are two more questions. The first one is that the alias "@fonts/xxx.woff2" or "@images/logo.png" in the css file cannot be used and can only be used through sass?
The second one is that the same style1.css + style2.css loaded in multiple pages of html. Can only be merged with common.css through scss?

the webpack alias of an asset (fonts, images) can be used in SCSS and in CSS too, e.g. background-image: url(@images/logo.png)

to merge many CSS files you can use the SCSS (import all CSS in single SCSS) or import many CSS files in one JS file, e.g. import '@styles/style1.css'; import '@styles/style2.css'; but import CSS in JS is bad practice
